# A list of string replacements in Python

Tags: python, string, replace

Is there a far shorter way to write the following code?

```
my_string = my_string.replace('A', '1')
my_string = my_string.replace('B', '2')
my_string = my_string.replace('C', '3')
my_string = my_string.replace('D', '4')
my_string = my_string.replace('E', '5')
```

Note that I don't need those exact values replaced; I'm simply looking for a way to turn 5+ lines into fewer than 5

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Looks like a good opportunity to use a loop:

```
mapping = { 'A':'1', 'B':'2', 'C':'3', 'D':'4', 'E':'5'}
for k, v in mapping.iteritems():
    my_string = my_string.replace(k, v)
```

A faster approach if you don't mind the parentheses would be:

```
mapping = [ ('A', '1'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '4'), ('E', '5') ]
for k, v in mapping:
    my_string = my_string.replace(k, v)
```

Comment: It's odd; that's the way I'd write it, because the problem is all about mapping from one character to another.

But really, you're not using the dict as a dict; you're using it as a list of tuples.  So why not write a list of tuples in the first place?

Comment: Certainly a list of tuples would also work (and be faster).  I'll edit the answer to include that option.

Comment: What if you will have this mapping { 'A':'1', '1':'A'} probably the result will not be the same as expected

Comment: A more concise way to define `mapping = zip(list('ABCDE'),range(1,6))`

Comment: For Python 3, use `.items()`  instead of  `.iteritems()`

Comment: @yhd.leung - even with that I get a "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" with python3 (worked perfectly in 2.7)

Answer (score 49):

You can easily use string.maketrans() to create the mapping string to pass to str.translate():

```
import string
trans = string.maketrans("ABCDE","12345")
my_string = my_string.translate(trans)
```

Comment: this is nice, but doesn't work in the case of multi-character patterns or replacements

Comment: Correct.  I assumed from the question that it was character-based replacement.

Comment: This is actually the only correct way to replace **simultaneously** a list of characters. For example, if you do `'<>'.replace('<', '>').replace('>','<')` you will get `'<<'`, but with translation you get `'><'`.

Comment: in python 3 it is str.maketrans("ABCDE", "12345")

Answer (score 15):

If you want to get the wrong answer, slowly, then use string.replace in a loop. (Though it does work in this case of no overlap among the patterns and replacements.)

For the general case with possible overlaps or a long subject string, use re.sub:

```
import re

def multisub(subs, subject):
    "Simultaneously perform all substitutions on the subject string."
    pattern = '|'.join('(%s)' % re.escape(p) for p, s in subs)
    substs = [s for p, s in subs]
    replace = lambda m: substs[m.lastindex - 1]
    return re.sub(pattern, replace, subject)

>>> multisub([('hi', 'bye'), ('bye', 'hi')], 'hi and bye')
'bye and hi'
```

For the special case of 1-character patterns and 1- or 0-character replacements, use string.maketrans.

Comment: +1 on the approach of using re.sub, -1 for saying that `string.replace` gives the wrong answer, since it's not clear exactly what *should* happen for overlapping matches.  So net 0 :)

Comment: str.replace can give an arguably wrong answer. For dictionary-based solutions, consider the string "wow" and translation table {'w': 'foo', 'o': 'bar'}.  Depending on the order that the dict iterates, you can end up with different results: "fbarbarbarfbarbar" or "foobarfoo". A function that gives different output for equal input is arguably broken.

Comment: Miles, yes, that's the kind of problem I meant. You could also run into overlaps in the keys alone, like 'hello' and 'hell'.

Answer (score 14):

Also look into [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate). It replaces characters according to a mapping you provide for Unicode strings, or otherwise must be told what to replace each character from chr(0) to chr(255) with.

Answer (score 9):

```
replaceDict = {'A':'1','B':'2','C':'3','D':'4','E':'5'}       
for key, replacement in replaceDict.items():  
  my_string = my_string.replace( key, replacement )
```

Answer (score 6):

I think it could be a little more efficient:

```
mapping = { 'A':'1', 'B':'2', 'C':'3', 'D':'4', 'E':'5'}
my_string = "".join([mapping[c] if c in mapping else c for c in my_string])
```

I suggest some benchmark with "timeit", with real cases in base of the lenght of "my_string".

Comment: this is the best solution IMO if you have multiple replacements at once and if the replacements are not always single characters.

Comment: Finally someone used a dictionary as it it was intended.  All others are O(n * m) but your method is O(n * log(m)) or better, where m is the size of the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line using Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

my_string="A B C test"

my_string =pd.DataFrame([my_string])[0].replace(["A","B","C","D","E"],['1','2','3','4','5'],regex=True)[0]

print(my_string)
'1 2 3 test'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I do it is with an associated array (a dictionary). Here is an example of the replacements I use when getting a file ready for deployment in LaTeX using regular expressions.

```
  import re
  def escapeTexString(string): # Returns TeX-friendly string
    rep = { # define desired replacements in this dictionary (mapping)
         '&': '\\&',
         '%': '\\%',
         '#': '\\#',
         '_': '\\_',
         '{': '\\{', # REGEX Special
         '}': '\\}', # REGEX Special
         '~': '\\char"007E{}', # LaTeX Special
         '$': '\\$', # REGEX Special
         '\\': '\\char"005C{}', # REGEX/LaTeX Special
         '^': '\\char"005E{}', # REGEX/LaTeX Special
         '"': '\\char"FF02{}'
        }
    # use these two lines to do the replacement (could be shortened to one line)
    pattern = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape,rep.keys()))) # Create single pattern object (key to simultaneous replacement)
    new_string = pattern.sub(lambda match: rep[match.group(0)], string)
    return new_string
```

Comment: Please read the other answers before posting. Your answer does exactly the same thing as Darius' answer from 8 years earlier.