# Python: efficient multi-string replace

Tags: python, replace, soundex

Can this function be made more efficient? I need to process a million names...

```
def indian_soundex_encode(s):
    s = s.replace("aa", "a")
    s = s.replace("ee", "i")
    s = s.replace("zh", "l")
    s = s.replace("oo", "u")
    s = s.replace("bu", "b")
    s = s.replace("dh", "d")
    s = s.replace("gh", "g")
    s = s.replace("jh", "j")
    s = s.replace("kh", "k")
    s = s.replace("sh", "s")
    s = s.replace("th", "t")
    s = s.replace("ck", "k")
    s = s.replace("kk", "k")
    s = s.replace("nn", "n")
    s = s.replace("mm", "m")
    s = s.replace("pp", "p")
    s = s.replace("ll", "l")
    s = s.replace("ty", "ti")
    s = s.replace("ot", "od")
    s = s.replace("iya", "ia")
    s = s.replace("ya", "ia")
    s = s.replace("sv", "s")
    s = s.replace("sw", "s")
    s = s.replace("my", "mi")
    return s
```

Comment: Here you have a similar question, and it's answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764360/a-list-of-string-replacements-in-python

Comment: On my computer, applying your function to 1,000,000 strings takes 4 seconds. Is that really too slow for your use case?

Comment: This is **NOT** a duplicate of the previous question! This poster specifically asks for efficiency, and the previous one for brevity/elegance of code. Not the same thing by a long shot.

Comment: Think about this: names are mostly short and contain only a few of these, so out of 24 only a few will actually do anything and the rest is just scanning the string. The longest Indian name I know is "Govindaraju Venkataraman" and it doesn't match any of the above (maybe it already went through the above encoding?).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919096/mass-string-replace-in-python

Comment: @NPE Good question, although to be fair it is not hard to imagine use cases where 4 seconds would be too slow - for example, the response to an HTTP request where the end user must wait for the answer. With the function written in C, the time would drop to 220ms, which is much more acceptable (although still not perfect).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. 4 seconds is fast enough for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be hard to make the function more efficient using pure Python. `str.replace` is already fairly efficient, but it does need to scan the strings many times and, at least in some cases, create several new strings. Replacing multiple calls to `replace` with a smarter algorithm that only scans the string once, would likely make the function slower because you'd be doing more work in pure Python and give up the raw efficiency of `str.replace`.

If writing a C extension module is possible in your case, I'd recommend doing that. Measuring with `timeit`, the following function outperforms the original one by a factor of ~17 (0.184 usec compared to 3.28 usec for the Python version) for the sample string `"foobaaar"`.

```
PyObject *
indian_soundex_encode(PyObject *ignore, PyObject *args)
{
  PyObject *py_s, *py_ret;
  bool replaced = false;
  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "S", &py_s))
    return NULL;

  const char *s = PyString_AS_STRING(py_s);
  Py_ssize_t len = PyString_GET_SIZE(py_s);
  char *ret = malloc(len + 1), *retptr = ret;
  if (!ret)
    return PyErr_NoMemory();

  while (len > 0) {
#define REPLACE(first, second, replacement)     \
    if (*s == first && *(s + 1) == second) {    \
      s += 2;                                   \
      len -= 2;                                 \
      *retptr++ = replacement;                  \
      replaced = true;                          \
      continue;                                 \
    }

    REPLACE('a', 'a', 'a');
    REPLACE('e', 'e', 'i');
    REPLACE('z', 'h', 'l');
    REPLACE('o', 'o', 'u');
    REPLACE('b', 'u', 'b');
    REPLACE('d', 'h', 'd');
    REPLACE('g', 'h', 'g');
    REPLACE('j', 'h', 'j');
    REPLACE('k', 'h', 'k');
    REPLACE('s', 'h', 's');
    REPLACE('t', 'h', 't');
    REPLACE('c', 'k', 'k');
    REPLACE('k', 'k', 'k');
    REPLACE('n', 'n', 'n');

#undef REPLACE
    *retptr++ = *s++;
    --len;
  }
  if (!replaced) {
    py_ret = py_s;
    Py_INCREF(py_ret);
  }
  else
    py_ret = PyString_FromStringAndSize(ret, retptr - ret);
  free(ret);
  return py_ret;
}
```

The above function can likely be further sped up with the use of `switch` statement or even more efficient lookup tables coded in C, but that is left as an exercise to the reader.

It would be another interesting exercise to try to code a version of this function in Cython, and compare its performance to the above hand-written C extension.

**Update:** The above C function corresponds to the original Python code in the question. The editor Jost snuck in a major code change along with the formatting change [in his edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7273471), which has apparently gone undetected by reviewers.