# Python multiple sub regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Initially having working script like this to go over the csv files in the folder and substitute a sub-string:

```
import fileinput
import os
import glob

#### Directory and file mask
this = r"C:\work\PythonScripts\Replacer\*.csv"
output_folder = "C:\\work\\PythonScripts\\Replacer\\"

#### Get files
files = glob.glob(this)

#### Section to replace
text_to_search = 'z'
replacement_text = 'ZZ_Top'

#### Loop through files and lines:
for f in files:
    head, tail = os.path.split(f)
    targetFileName = os.path.join(head, output_folder, tail)

    with fileinput.FileInput(targetFileName, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            print(line.replace(text_to_search, replacement_text), end='')
```

There came a necessity to substitute several Word quotes and long hyphen. So I thought of using something like this in the cycle above:

```
s = '’ ‘ ’ ‘ ’ – “ ” “ – ’'
print(s)
print(s.replace('’', '\'').replace('‘', '\'').replace('–','-').replace('“','"').replace('”','"'))
```

==>

```
’ ‘ ’ ‘ ’ – “ ” “ – ’
' ' ' ' ' - " " " - '
```

But then I came across the following comment of using regex sub function:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/765835

So I tried it and it worked fine on its own:

```
import re

def multisub(subs, subject):
 #   "Simultaneously perform all substitutions on the subject string."
    pattern = '|'.join('(%s)' % re.escape(p) for p, s in subs)
    substs = [s for p, s in subs]
    replace = lambda m: substs[m.lastindex - 1]
    return re.sub(pattern, replace, subject)

print(multisub([('’', '\''), ('‘', '\''), ('–','-'), ('“','"'), ('”','"')], '1’ 2‘ 1’ 2‘ 1’ 3– 4“ 5” 4“ 3– 2’'))
```

==>

```
1' 2' 1' 2' 1' 3- 4" 5" 4" 3- 2'
```

But as soon as I sticked it to the original script it runs but doesn't modify the file:

```
import fileinput
import os
import glob
import re

#### Directory and file mask
this = r"C:\work\PythonScripts\Replacer\*.csv"
output_folder = "C:\\work\\PythonScripts\\Replacer\\"

#### RegEx substitution func
def multisub(subs, subject):
 #   "Simultaneously perform all substitutions on the subject string."
    pattern = '|'.join('(%s)' % re.escape(p) for p, s in subs)
    substs = [s for p, s in subs]
    replace = lambda m: substs[m.lastindex - 1]
    return re.sub(pattern, replace, subject)

#### Get files
files = glob.glob(this)

#### Loop through files and lines:
for f in files:
    head, tail = os.path.split(f)
    targetFileName = os.path.join(head, output_folder, tail)

    with fileinput.FileInput(targetFileName, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            print(multisub([('’', '\''), ('‘', '\''), ('–','-'), ('“','"'), ('”','"')], line), end='')
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the code is working by itself. The missing piece was that it was running on Windows, so I had to add PYTHONUTF8 system variable with value of 1 to Environment Variables. After this the original code was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works for me as is when I test it, but you have a lot of unnecessary processing in there that may be introducing errors. The big advantage of using `fileinput` over regular `open` is that it can loop through lines in multiple files without needing another loop to open each file individually. So try this and see if it works:

```
#### Get files
files = glob.glob(this)

#### Loop through files and lines:
for line in fileinput.input(files, inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
    print(multisub([('’', '\''), ('‘', '\''), ('–','-'), ('“','"'), ('”','"')], line), end='')
```

Comment: For some reason, having a csv file containing the chars in the folder I end up with empty file using this code...